# JPA repository save method inserts NULL values in MySQL instead of values provided by json request

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm new to spring. I want to add a row in MySQL database by a post request using POSTMAN via Spring boot project.

I send a post request with a json body providing neccessary values for the table. but when I check the table I see that NULL values are inserted in table. Can you please help me prevent inserting null values in table.
CODE
AuthConroller.java Class

```
import com.hackernewsclient.com.hackernewsclient.dto.ResgisterRequest;
import com.hackernewsclient.com.hackernewsclient.service.AuthService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {


    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity signup(@RequestBody ResgisterRequest resgisterRequest) {
        authService.signup(resgisterRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

User.java entity class

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

AuthService.java class

```
import com.hackernewsclient.com.hackernewsclient.dto.ResgisterRequest;
import com.hackernewsclient.com.hackernewsclient.model.User;
import com.hackernewsclient.com.hackernewsclient.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AuthService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void signup(ResgisterRequest resgisterRequest) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(resgisterRequest.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(resgisterRequest.getPassword());
        user.setEmail(resgisterRequest.getEmail());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    
}
```

UserRepository.java interface

```
import com.hackernewsclient.com.hackernewsclient.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

RegisterRequest.java Data Object class for post request's body

```
public class ResgisterRequest {

    private String user_name;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public String getUsername() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        email = email;
    }
}
```

Screenshot of POSTMAN - my request attempt which its status is successful

[image]

Screenshot of User table values in MySQL phpmyadmin

[image]

Intellij Log

```
Hibernate: insert into user (email, password, user_name) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have issues in `ResgisterRequest` setters. `username = username;` assigns value to the same variable. It should be `this.user_name = user_name;`

```
class ResgisterRequest {

    private String user_name;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: That´s why it is usually best to have some kind of linter active or auto-generate them.